# Can a list and variables be returned from a function?

Tags: python, call, return-value

I can do this..

```
def funcOne():
    a,b = funcTwo()
    print a, b

def funcTwo():
    .....
    ......   
    return x, y
```

But can a list also be returned from funcTwo and displayed in funcOne ALONG with the 2 values? Nothing seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you return multiple values, all you are doing is building a single tuple containing those values, and returning it. You can construct tuples with anything in it, and a list comes under anything:

```
def funcOne():
    a, b, some_list = funcTwo()
    print a, b, some_list

def funcTwo():
    ...
    some_list = [...] 
    return x, y, some_list
```

If you mean you wish to return the values from the list, you can do that by just returning the list, unpacking works with lists too:

```
def funcOne():
    a, b, = funcTwo()
    print a, b

def funcTwo():
    ...
    some_list = [x, y] 
    return some_list
```

Or if you want to extend the returned values with all the values from a list, you just need to concatenate a list of values you wish to return with the list of extra values:

```
def funcOne():
    a, b, c, d = funcTwo()
    print a, b, c, d

def funcTwo():
    ...
    some_list = [z, w] 
    return [x, y] + some_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def list_and_vars():
    a, b = "fee", "fi"
    c = ["fo", "fum"]
    return a, b, c

>>> print list_and_vars()
('fee', 'fi', ['fo', 'fum'])
>>> a, b, [c, d] = list_and_vars()
>>> a, b, c, d
('fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def funcOne():
    f2x,f2y = funcTwo() #tuple unpacking var1,var2 = (val1,val2)
    print a,b,list((lf2x,f2y)) #convert tuple to list

def funcTwo(): 
    return x, y #actually returns (x,y)
```

If we look at the following

```
def funcTwo():
    return 'a','b'
print(funcTwo())
```

We can see that `funcTwo` returns a *tuple* containing `'a','b'`:

```
>>> 
('a', 'b')
```

In this way Python does only return one value, however it's tuple unpacking can make it look like this isn't the case:

```
var1,var2 = funcTwo()
print(var1)
print(var2)
>>> 
a
b
```

You *could* return a list explicitly:

```
def funcTwo():
    return ['a','b']
print(funcTwo())
```

In which case you are still returning one value, it's simply a list. For example:

```
def funcTwo():
    return ['a','b']
def funcOne():
    return 'c','d',funcTwo()
print(funcOne())
```

Would print

```
>>> 
('c', 'd', ['a', 'b'])
```

Again you can see, we've only returned *one* value, a tuple which consists of all the values we desired to return.

If you wanted to simply print something in `funcOne` unless you used string formatting you would get the same result as if you had `print`-ed the return values because `print('a','b','c')` prints `('a','b','c')` however you could do something like:

```
def funcOne():
    print(','.join(['c','d',funcTwo().__repr__()]))
>>> 
c,d,['a', 'b']
```